# Can python's mechanize use localhost sites?

Tags: python, mechanize

Can Mechanize access sites being locally hosted by Apache?

Comment: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Comment: Just a thought: are you trying `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1`?  If the former doesn't work, try the latter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It can use any URL available so long as it is reachable. Just make sure it's properly formatted!

Answer (score 0):

How about trying it out?  Well, seriously, I used [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) (a wrapper around mechanize) on localhost, and it worked. It just wants to make a http connection without knowing where it is.  Is this the answer you expected?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. So now im trying to find out if the url doesnt work or my code.

Comment: @shorty876 - ok, sorry about my sarcasm